# Hypothesis testing Exercise

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

A survey of 100 randomly selected motorist reveals that 57 are unhappy with the state of the roads. test the null hypothesis that half of motorists in the population are unhappy with the state of the roads.

$H_0:P=0.5$

$H_1:P\neq 0.5$

at which levels of 1, 5 and 10 percent significance can $H_0$ be rejected?

can someone explain this. i know its a binomial(bernoulli) but it lacks the standard deviation.... thanks for solution example how to define.

Answer (score 2):

$n=100$

$X_1,\dots X_n$ i.i.d. $B(p)$.

Let's compute the p-value, which is $P_{H_0}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\geq 57)=P_{H_0}(Y\geq 57)$

We know that under $H_0$, $Y=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is approximately normal with mean $np_0=50$ and variance $np_0(1-p_0)=25$.

So $P_{H_0}(Y\geq 57)=P(\mathcal{N}(50,5)\geq 57)=P(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq (57-50)/5)=1-\Phi(1.4)\simeq 0.08$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard gaussian distribution.

So if the level of the test is $1\%$ or $5\%$ you don't reject. If it's $10\%$, you reject.

Comment: the solution is: the null hypothesis cannot be rejected at the 10% significance level. Is this due to the circumstance that the 10% has to be splitted into 5% to for a two-tailed test??? we are doing this with x_mean - mean / divided through standarddeviation...

Comment: (57-50)/5 = 1.4 =>0.9192 ND

Comment: ok. we are both wrong. because of unknown Var we have to use the t-table students distribution. there we go to alpha/2 which equalls t= 1.66 for 10% sign.level.

Comment: also the higher sign. level the smaller aceptance range and the likelier to reject 0 hypothesis. so i don't get why you reject 10% and 5 and 1 % not. Am i so completely wrong or are you??